# How to use jetpack compose @Preview for xml view?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

is there a way to display xml view inside jetpack compose @Preview?

Context: migrating to jetpack compose, and I will use Showkase lib for design system but it works only from composables.

Comment: What is your definition of "xml view"? Do you mean a layout resource? If so, then AFAIK `@Preview` does not support that, unless you create a composable using `AndroidView` that wraps that layout resource.